# Pygame running extremely slow

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to code a simple snake game with Pygame. For some reason, the game is running extremely slowly, at around 1.3 frames per second. I tested it on both my MacBook Pro and a Windows laptop and it runs at the same speed on both. The project is distributed across multiple files, so I'll link the github: https://github.com/achandra03/snake-rl. The relevant parts are the `run.py` file and the `Game` folder.

Here are a few files which I think are the most relevant:

`run.py` (main driver class):

```
import snake_rl
import pygame
import random
from brain import Brain
from snake_rl.envs.snake_env import SnakeEnv
import keras
from keras import models
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import losses
import os

(width, height) = (600, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
env = SnakeEnv(screen)

done = False
while not done:
  env.render()
  pressed = False
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      break
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      pressed = True
      done = False
      key = event.key
      if key == pygame.K_UP:
        done = env.step(0)['done']
      elif key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        done = env.step(1)['done']
      elif key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        done = env.step(2)['done']
      elif key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        done = env.step(3)['done']
      elif key == pygame.K_a:
        done = env.step(pygame.K_a)['done']
  if not pressed:
    done = env.step(env.snake.head.direction)['done']
  if done == True:
    pygame.quit()
  env.render()
```

`snake_env.py` (environment manager):

```
from Game.Snake import Snake
from Game.Food import Food

import pygame
import random
import numpy as np
import sys
from PIL import Image


class SnakeEnv():

    def create_food(self):
        x = random.randint(0, 19)
        y = random.randint(0, 19)
        while(self.snake.board[x, y] == 1 or self.snake.board[x, y] == 2):
            x = random.randint(0, 19)
            y = random.randint(0, 19)
        self.food = Food(self.screen, x * 30, y * 30)
        self.snake.update_food(x, y)
        self.snake.board[x, y] = 5

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.action_space = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
        self.state = None
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = screen
        self.snake = Snake(self.screen)
        self.create_food()
        self.state = self.snake.board
        self.total_reward = 0

    def reset(self):
        self.__init__()

    def screenshot(self):
        data = pygame.image.tostring(self.screen, 'RGB')
        image = Image.frombytes('RGB', (600, 600), data)
        matrix = np.asarray(image.getdata(), dtype=np.uint8)
        matrix = (matrix - 128)/(128 - 1)
        matrix = np.reshape(matrix, (1, 600, 600, 3))
        return matrix

    def step(self, action):
        d = dict()
        d['state'] = self.screenshot()
        self.snake.move(action)
        reward = 0
        done = False
        if(self.snake.head.x == self.food.x and self.snake.head.y == self.food.y):
            self.create_food()
            self.snake.add_body()
            reward += 1
        else:
            lost = self.snake.check_loss()
            if lost == 1:
                reward = -1
                done = True
        self.total_reward += reward
        d['action'] = action
        d['reward'] = reward
        self.state = self.snake.board
        d['next_state'] = self.screenshot()
        d['done'] = done
        return d


    def get_state(self):
        return np.reshape(self.snake.board, (400, 1)).T / 5

    def render(self):
        self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.food.render()
        self.snake.render()
        for r in self.snake.List:
            pygame.display.update(r.rect)

    def close(self):
        pygame.quit()

    def move(self, key):
        self.snake.move(key)
```

`Snake.py` (controls the snake):

```
import pygame
from Game.Body import Body
import numpy as np

class Snake:

    def __init__(self, window):
        self.head = Body(window, 0, 0, None)
        self.List = [self.head]
        self.window = window
        self.board = np.zeros((20, 20))
        self.board.fill(0.1)
        self.board[0, 0]= 2
        self.food_x = 0
        self.food_y = 0

    def render(self):
        for body in self.List:
            body.render()

    def update_board(self):
        self.board = np.zeros((20, 20))
        self.board.fill(0.1)
        self.board[self.food_x, self.food_y] = 5
        for body in self.List:
            body.move()
            x = body.y // 30
            y = body.x // 30
            if(body.ahead is None):
                try:
                    self.board[x, y] = 2
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                self.board[x, y] = 1

    def move(self, key):
        if key == 3 and self.List[0].direction != 1:
            self.List[0].direction = 3
        elif key == 0 and self.List[0].direction != 2:
            self.List[0].direction = 0
        elif key == 1 and self.List[0].direction != 3:
            self.List[0].direction = 1
        elif key == 2 and self.List[0].direction != 0:
            self.List[0].direction = 2
        elif key == pygame.K_a:
            print(self.head.old_x)
            print(self.head.old_y)
            return
        self.update_board()

    def add_body(self):
        x = self.List[len(self.List) - 1].old_y
        y = self.List[len(self.List) - 1].old_x
        b = Body(self.window, x, y, self.List[len(self.List) - 1])
        self.List.append(b)
        direction = self.List[len(self.List) - 2].direction
        b.set_direction(direction)

    def check_loss(self):
        if(self.head.x >= 600 or self.head.x < 0 or self.head.y >= 600 or self.head.y < 0):
            #pygame.quit()
            return 1
        else:
            for body in self.List:
                if body is not self.head and body.x == self.head.x and body.y == self.head.y:
                    #pygame.quit()
                    return 1
        return 0

    def update_food(self, x, y):
        self.food_x = y
        self.food_y = x

    def take_action(self, action):
        if action == 0:
            self.move(pygame.K_UP)
        elif action == 1:
            self.move(pygame.K_RIGHT)
        elif action == 2:
            self.move(pygame.K_DOWN)
        elif action == 3:
            self.move(pygame.K_LEFT)
```

`Body.py` (controls the individual body segments):

```
import pygame
from pygame import Rect

class Body:
    """
    0 - up
    1 - right
    2 - down
    3 - left
    """
    def __init__(self, window, x, y, ahead):
        self.direction = 2
        self.window = window
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.old_x = x
        self.old_y = y
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 30, 30)
        self.ahead = ahead

    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.window, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, 30, 30))

    def set_direction(self, direction):
        self.direction = direction

    def move(self):
        if(self.ahead is None):
            self.old_x = self.y
            self.old_y = self.x
            if self.direction == 0:
                self.y -= 30
            elif self.direction == 1:
                self.x += 30
            elif self.direction == 2:
                self.y += 30
            elif self.direction == 3:
                self.x -= 30
        else:
            self.old_x = self.y
            self.old_y = self.x
            self.direction = self.ahead.direction
            self.x = self.ahead.old_y
            self.y = self.ahead.old_x
```

Comment: Post the relevant code here, not a link to the relevant code. Also creating a minimal reproducable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would be helpful here

Comment: @NotZack just did

Comment: You might have better luck at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Comment: That said, I can't even begin to guess why you're importing a bunch of Keras stuff for a simple snake game. What do you need AI techniques for?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it's part of a larger project, I'm doing stuff with reinforcement learning

Answer (score 0):

dont know but try upgrading to pygame 2 u can download it with

```
    python3 -m pip install -U pygame==2.0.0.dev6 --user
```

it should work atleast

pygame 2 runs faster than normal pygame

Comment: Also try upgrading to lates version of python.